# I want to return the name of the named range from a worksheet that a cell value can be found in to another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

The cleaners worksheet has the named references (Each Cleaner in the worksheet is its named range, Cleaner 1-19). Each cleaner has a drop down list that is used to allocate a room to them.
The colours tab is used to show which room is being allocated to a cleaner in a list.

If the room T1 has been allocated to Cleaner 1 in the Cleaners Worksheet that cleaner needs to appear in the Colour worksheet next to the room name.

I am not VBA savvy, sorry!

[Cleaners Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOQwF.png)
[Colours Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuab6.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot also from the Cleaners sheet. But also clarify what exactly the goal is. Is it simply to show the name of the cleaner that has this room selected from the dropdown list in the Cleaners sheet?

Comment: Sounds like MATCH would return the matching row where the room T1 is first referenced, then you could just mash this together eg "Cleaner "&MATCH(<Room>,<ColumnOfRooms>,0)